# Rails has_many with nested condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called `site`.

`site has_many site_settings`
`site_settings belongs_to setting`
`setting` has a boolean field called `temporary`

I want the relashionship between `site` and `site_settings` to return only the `site_settings` that are not associated to a temporary `setting`.

I have tried:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :site_settings, :dependent => :destroy, 
    :conditions => {:setting => {:temporary => false} }
```

I also have tried some things with `Proc.new`, but with no success.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to join/include Setting:

```
has_many :site_settings, :dependent => :destroy, :include => :setting, :conditions => {:setting => {:temporary => false}}
```